# Undefined offset: 0 (Oscommerce bm.categories.php)

Tags: php, oscommerce

I have an issue with a file in oscommerce. In a customized bm_categories.php file I get a error:

**Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in xxx\includes\modules\boxes\bm_categories.php on line 52**

Here is the code. 
I have marked Line 52 with : //THIS IS LINE 52//
I really hope someone can give me a hint.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
  $Id$

  osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
  http://www.oscommerce.com

  Copyright (c) 2010 osCommerce

  Released under the GNU General Public License
  Modfied by Kevin Neufeld
  Date: Novemeber 16, 2010
  Released as contributions: Decenber 9th, 2010

*/

  class bm_categories {
    var $code = 'bm_categories';
    var $group = 'boxes';
    var $title;
    var $description;
    var $sort_order;
    var $enabled = false;

    function bm_categories() {
      $this->title = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_TITLE;
      $this->description = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION;

      if ( defined('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS') ) {
        $this->sort_order = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER;
        $this->enabled = (MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS == 'True');

        $this->group = ((MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT == 'Left Column') ? 'boxes_column_left' : 'boxes_column_right');
      }
    }

    function tep_show_category($counter) {
      global $tree, $categories_string, $cPath_array, $pCounter;           //added $pCounter
      //additional Variables
      //$pCounter is also globally defined and initialized in getData() and gets changed at the end of this function

      $nCounter = $tree[$counter]['next_id'];

     //Get item Levels
     if($pCounter == 0){
       $pLevel = 0;
     }else{
       $pLevel = $tree[$pCounter]['level'];
     }

      $cLevel = $tree[$counter]['level'];

//<---- THIS IS LINE 52 ------>//
     $nLevel = $tree[$nCounter]['level'];


      //Start of UnsortedList <ul> if Category level > 0
      if($cLevel > 0){
        if($cLevel != $pLevel){
            $categories_string .= '<ul class="level ' . $cLevel . '">';
        }
      }

      //Start of ListItem <li> and determines if List Item is Current
      if (isset($cPath_array) && in_array($counter, $cPath_array)) {
        if($cLevel == 0){
          $categories_string .= '<li id="current" class=" active item'.$counter.'"><a href="';
        }else{
          $categories_string .= '<li class="item'.$counter.'"><a href="';
        }
      }else{
        $categories_string .= '<li class="item'.$counter.'"><a href="';
      }

      //Gets and inserts URL path for link
      if ($tree[$counter]['parent'] == 0) {
        $cPath_new = 'cPath=' . $counter;
      } else {
        $cPath_new = 'cPath=' . $tree[$counter]['path'];
      }

      $categories_string .= tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $cPath_new) . '">';

      //Gets CatgoryCounts if Set in Admin -- Seperator is also located here
      if (SHOW_COUNTS == 'true') {
        $products_in_category = tep_count_products_in_category($counter);
        if ($products_in_category > 0) {
          $showCount_string = '<span class="countSeperator">&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;</span><span class="showCounts">[' . $products_in_category . ']</span>';
        }
      }

      //Start of Span <span> around Category Name
      if (isset($cPath_array) && in_array($counter, $cPath_array)) {
        $categories_string .= '<span class="itemParentName">' . $tree[$counter]['name'] . '</span></a>';
      } else {
        $categories_string .= '<span class="itemName">'. $tree[$counter]['name'] . '</span></a></li>';
      }

      //This is used to determin the level and place the correct number of closing tags  
      if($cLevel > 0){
        if ($cLevel > $nLevel){
          $j = abs($cLevel - $nLevel);
          $categories_string .= str_repeat('</ul></li>', $j);
        }elseif ($nCounter == false){
          $categories_string .= str_repeat('</ul></li>', $tree[$counter]['level']);
        }
     }

      $pCounter = $counter;

      if ($tree[$counter]['next_id'] != false) {
        $this->tep_show_category($tree[$counter]['next_id']);
      }
    }

    function getData() {
      global $categories_string, $tree, $languages_id, $cPath, $cPath_array, $pCounter;           //added $pCounter
      $pCounter = 0;        //initialize $pCounter
      $categories_string = '';
      $tree = array();

      $categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '0' and c.categories_status = 1 and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='" . (int)$languages_id ."' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");
      while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query))  {
        $tree[$categories['categories_id']] = array('name' => $categories['categories_name'],
                                                    'parent' => $categories['parent_id'],
                                                    'level' => 0,
                                                    'path' => $categories['categories_id'],
                                                    'next_id' => false);

        if (isset($parent_id)) {
          $tree[$parent_id]['next_id'] = $categories['categories_id'];
        }

        $parent_id = $categories['categories_id'];

        if (!isset($first_element)) {
          $first_element = $categories['categories_id'];
        }
      }

      if (tep_not_null($cPath)) {
        $new_path = '';
        reset($cPath_array);
        while (list($key, $value) = each($cPath_array)) {
          unset($parent_id);
          unset($first_id);
          $categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '" . (int)$value . "' and c.categories_status = 1 and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='" . (int)$languages_id ."' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");
          if (tep_db_num_rows($categories_query)) {
            $new_path .= $value;
            while ($row = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)) {
              $tree[$row['categories_id']] = array('name' => ''.$row['categories_name'],
                                                   'parent' => $row['parent_id'],
                                                   'level' => $key+1,
                                                   'path' => $new_path . '_' . $row['categories_id'],
                                                   'next_id' => false);

              if (isset($parent_id)) {
                $tree[$parent_id]['next_id'] = $row['categories_id'];
              }

              $parent_id = $row['categories_id'];

              if (!isset($first_id)) {
                $first_id = $row['categories_id'];
              }

              $last_id = $row['categories_id'];
            }
            $tree[$last_id]['next_id'] = $tree[$value]['next_id'];
            $tree[$value]['next_id'] = $first_id;
            $new_path .= '_';
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      $this->tep_show_category($first_element);

      $data = '<div id="categoryBoxContainer" class="ui-widget infoBoxContainer">' .
              '  <div class="ui-widget-header infoBoxHeading">' . MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_BOX_TITLE . '</div>' .
              '  <div class="ui-widget-content infoBoxContents" style="background-color:#f5f5f5; border:none;"><ul class="menu">' . $categories_string . '</ul></div>' .
              '</div>';


      return $data;
    }

    function execute() {
      global $SID, $oscTemplate;

      if ((USE_CACHE == 'true') && empty($SID)) {
        $output = tep_cache_categories_box();
      } else {
        $output = $this->getData();
      }

      $oscTemplate->addBlock($output, $this->group);
    }

    function isEnabled() {
      return $this->enabled;
    }

    function check() {
      return defined('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS');
    }

    function install() {
      tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Enable Categories Module', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS', 'True', 'Do you want to add the module to your shop?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'True\', \'False\'), ', now())");
      tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Content Placement', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'Left Column', 'Should the module be loaded in the left or right column?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'Left Column\', \'Right Column\'), ', now())");
      tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, date_added) values ('Sort Order', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER', '0', 'Sort order of display. Lowest is displayed first.', '6', '0', now())");
    }

    function remove() {
      tep_db_query("delete from " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " where configuration_key in ('" . implode("', '", $this->keys()) . "')");
    }

    function keys() {
      return array('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER');
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this. if $tree has index 0 then get its value else set it to empty string or whatever you want

```
$nLevel = isset($tree[$nCounter]['level']) ? $tree[$nCounter]['level'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

It means, that your array has no key with the value `0`. Check the `$tree` array:

```
var_dump( $tree );
```

and see what's inside there.

Seems, that:

```
$nCounter = $tree[$counter]['next_id'];
```

has no value in it; might id be, that there is no `next_id` ? If so, then check with `isset` before posting it:

```
$nLevel = (isset($tree[$nCounter]['level']) ? $tree[$nCounter]['level'] : '');
```

or add the same check when setting `nCounter`:

```
$nCounter = (isset($tree[$counter]['next_id']) ? $tree[$counter]['next_id'] : 0);
```